Village girl with sensitive ears wants to get into music school
I'm looking for a non-English movie in which the girl is from a village and she wants to get into a music school as she plays violin. She has very sensitive ears as she has sex with anybody who kisses her ears. She tries to cut her ears out of anger for cheating on a guy she likes with her teacher.
Could you tell me the name of the movie?

Please elaborate on "non-English". When did you watch this?

Should be german or french.Not sure

Finally got the name of the movie after these many days of search. The name is LelleBelle (2010).

19-year old violinist Belle lives in a small farming village in the Netherlands. Everyone around her seems obsessed with sex: her boyfriend, her sister and especially her mother. But Belle's only interest is her violin, and she is put off by the constant flirting and mating of her peers. 


Remember that you can (and should) accept your own answer.
